# Checking duplicates in an array, and removing them is worst-case complexity O(n^2) or O(n^3)?

Tags: c, algorithm, duplicates, time-complexity

I am trying to evaluate this algorithm:

- checking equality is O(n<sup>2</sup>)
- removing an element is O(n)

So I think the entire algorithm will be O(n^3) in the worst case.

```
    for (i = 0; i < ne-1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i+1; j < ne; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(array[i].id, array[j].id)==0)
            {
                cont++;   

                for (k = j; k < ne - 1; k++)  
                    array[k] = array[k + 1];
                ne--;   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this valid C code?

Comment: Yes, array is a struct that contains 3 filed of type char[20]

Comment: Could you please replace your current code with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I don't see where any of your variables are declared, for instance.

Comment: @Elogent Isn't that irrelevant to the actual question?

Comment: Rewrite code to *only* show the worst case and see for yourself. It is hard to understand what you don't know and where you have problem with estimate. Also saving bytes on variable names makes it very painful to understand intention of the code.

Comment: @immibis Regardless, an MCVE certainly can't hurt.

Comment: Are you just wanting confirmation of the time complexity, or are you also looking for improvements?

Comment: I don't think that algorithm works. After you find that array[j] is the same as array[i], you replace array[j] with array[j+1]. Then you increment j so the next element you compare with array[i] is what used to be at array[j+2]. The element moved to array[j] never gets checked, so if it is equal to array[i] as well, you'll end up with a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you are correct that the cost of comparison is O(n<sup>2</sup>) and the cost of deleting an element is O(n), the inter-relationship between the two actions results in the entire algorithm being O(n<sup>2</sup>). Since O(n<sup>2</sup>) is in O(n<sup>3</sup>), it is not incorrect to say that the algorithm is O(n<sup>3</sup>), but that is not a tight bound.

To see why, consider the cost presented by some element of the array. It will either be compared (as `array[i]`) with every following element, or it will be removed, involving a shift of all following elements. But not both; once it has been removed, it will never be the element used in the outer loop.

In either case, the cost of the element is the number of following elements, and the total cost of the algorithm is worst-case n(n-1)/2, which is O(n<sup>2</sup>). (If elements are deleted, the actual cost will be less; the worst case occurs if there are no duplicates.)

As @Amit notes, if the cost of performing a comparison or a move is not O(1), that will have to be taken into account, resulting in O(n<sup>2</sup> m) where m is the cost of a comparison or assignment. But it would be normal to consider that cost to be fixed.

As I noted in a comment, the algorithm as presented is incorrect. The correct algorithm would be:

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; ) {
        if (IsEqual(a[i], a[j])) {
            for (k = j; k < n - 1; ++k)  
                a[k] = a[k + 1];
            --n;   
        } else {
            ++j;
        }
    }
}
```

Normally, a better solution is to sort the array, which will mean that equal elements will be adjacent, and then do a single O(n) pass to compress the result; that is O(n log n) (from the sort) but does not preserve order. (You can preserve order with an auxiliary array, though.)

Comment: thanks for your reply, anyway I was thinking a better implementation to find duplicates. Do you think is possible implementing hash table ? If I can , I could do a complexity of O(1). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user3289840: a hash table is good. It O(n), not O(1), since you need to handle all n elements. Better said, O(1) *on average*.

Comment: Using hash table, how can I handle collision? It might be a duplicates or a collision, is this possible?

Comment: @user3289840: Every hash table has some mechanism for handling collisions. Look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it would be **O(n<sup>3</sup> m)** where *m* is the length of the `id` string (or the average length of the `id` strings).

The `i`th part is *O(n)*, and so is `j`. You the compare *m* characters for each iteration and then `k` is another *O(n)*. It might be possible to show that the amortized complexity is lower though since every iteration of `k` reduces *n*, but that requires deeper analysis.